# Content Tagging with our own Taxonomy/Tags Items using third party Content Tagging Service Provider

Tags: taxonomy, cortex

Content Tagging with our own Taxonomy/Tags Items Repository using third party Content Analyzer Service Provider.

The out of the box Open Calais or Sitecore provides flexibility to connect with Azure Cognitive Services/Google Cloud Natural Language Insightful text analysis and all providers to integrate but doesn't provide the option to use our own Tag/Taxonomy Repository.

How can we accomplish where the Open Calais or Azure Cognitive Services **only makes a decision based on the content analysis and provide a tag from our own Tag Repository** instead of their millions of tags repository where it returns a lot of noise, irrelevant tags.

I couldn't find any blog and all blogs like below are only showing how to pull tags from outside but couldn't find any blog where we can provide content and also use our own tag repository.

https://smartsitecore.com/en/building-custom-cortex-content-tagging/
https://mskutta.github.io/2019/09/16/sitecore-cortex-content-tagging-with-azure-cognitive-services-text-analytics-named-entities/